# How can I select multiple values of a [type=""] selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select all the inputs of type `text`, `email` or `tel`.

Can I do that with one selector? For example:

```
input[type=text][type=email][type=tel]
```

(I know this one does not work)

Or the only way is to separate them by commas?

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=tel]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating by commas and repeating the `input` part is currently the only way. As you may have guessed, chaining all the attribute selectors together essentially means that the type must be all of those values, which cannot possibly happen.